# Can't format columns on DataGridView bound to List<T>

Tags: winforms, list, datagridview

I'm binding a list of objects to a datagridview and having issues with the display:
This is my custom class

```
public class Line
{
    private int _sequence;
    public int Sequence {get { } set { }}

    private string _dataTime;
    public string DataTime {get { } set { }}

    private string _content;
    public string Content {get { } set { }}

    public Line(int sequence, string dateTime, string content)
    {
        _sequence = sequence;
        _dataTime = dateTime;
        _content = content;
        IsBookmarked = false;
    }
}
```

I bind the List:

```
List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
// lines is initialized with values

DataGridView dataGrid = new DataGridView();
dataGrid.DataSource = Lines
```

The DataGridView displays the contents of the list without issues. However the columns are very narrow so I want to format the columns:

```
dataGrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

And here I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Checking the dataGrid.Columns.Count in runtime I see that is it '0' and not 3 as I'd expect.

Comment: I think you are binding list and creating gridview object at runtime otherwise it would have work perfectly? I mean placing the grid on form and if you write the Autosize code on form load for that grid.

Comment: I am creating the datagridview and binding in runtime. I can create the columns themselves in runtime and format them, but then I get these pre-made columns, and new columns display the properties from the class (so I have 6 columns instead of 3 and 3 of the columns are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the property on the grid instead of each individual column:

*Set the DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode property to Fill to set the sizing mode for all columns that do not override this value.*

[from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd004dhd.aspx)

Comment: That is an option but I rather not set all the columns to fill.